# Reduce AWS Client VPN Billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, aws-vpn

My AWS Client VPN cost is getting high, is there any way i can decrease it ?

Things i had done to reduce cost currently is enabling Split-tunnel in vpn.

Comment: all cloud providers are very expensive if you want to reduce costs check for other alternatives (colocation/dedicated, etc) but this also could be more expensive (time-wise) to bootstrap, setup, etc, at the ends is a tradeoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I would suggest is automating the client VPN associations.

Client VPN associations and connections are the only cost part that will increase the cost.

Other than this look at [split tunnels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/split-tunnel-vpn.html) which would stop all network traffic going through the VPN (which may present AWS network costs)

Comment: I already enabled split tunnelling as mentioned in the my question. Will check automating VPN association .Thanks